# Split string into multiple string separated

Tags: c#, string

I have a string "What is Facebook?.| A. Website B. Internet C. Social Network D. Game"
How can I split and stored that string into 5 string separated in C# programming? I try to split with my code but the result I have just a mess.

What result I expect is that after split, I have 5 string variable separated like:

```
string A = "What is Facebook?"
string B = "A. Website"
string C = "B. Internet"
string D = "C. Social Network"
string E = "D. Game"
```

That is my code:

```
String value = "What is Facebook?.| A. Website B. Internet C. Social Network D. Game";
Char delimiter = '|';            
String[] substrings = value.Split(delimiter);
```

Comment: You need another split to split the second part. Have you tried anything for it? You can try with regex.

Comment: What precisely were you expecting as output of your "split"?  Currently you'd only get two strings if you split on the '|'.

Comment: You may need to write a RegExp, like this one: `^(.*)\|.*(A\..*)(B\..*)(C\..*)(D\..*)$`

Comment: Sometime, no matter what you do, this split is going to fail.

Comment: If you can change the pattern.... Best do so.. Just add a `|` at the beginning of each section

Comment: @AndreyNasonov saviour

Comment: @GiladGreen I try your suggest and get the result match with what I want. But how to stored the output string into 5 string variable separated?

Comment: @AndreyNasonov I do like you said String pattern = "^ (.*)\|.* (A\..*)(B\..*)(C\..*)(D\..*)$"; but C# return an error: "Unrecognized escape sequence"

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47293010/edit) your question to show us what you are doing. The result of the regex will include the five separated strings in the `Groups` property. To put Andrey's regex into a C# string you need to precede it with `@`.

Answer (score 1):

You can split by [`\|?\s+(?=[A-Z]\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/rWL4Cv/1) :

```
string[] substrings = Regex.Split(value, @"\|?\s+(?=[A-Z]\.)");
```

Comment: It's return nothing :((

Comment: I see. Your demo output fine. But not exactly my result I expect. You just print out only once string value, but what I need is output separate value like: string A = "What is Facebook?" and string B = "A. Website" and string C = "B.Social media" and etc.... Hope u can help me solve this problem. By the way, thanks so much Slai.

Comment: ahhh yeah yeah! I see! It's work fine. You use string.Join() method so the result output all value. If I just want each value separated, so I just do substring[0] and so on.... Thanks @Slai !!! U just save me from the hell ~~

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I would create a simple class that holds a question and the possible answers. This way, you can parse your string into a class which can do other fancy things, like display itself correctly, and could contain a property that indicates the index of the correct answer (so you can compare the user's selection with the correct index).

For example, this class has a static `Parse` method that takes in your string and returns an instance of the class. It also overrides `ToString` so that it displays the Question and Answers in a nice way:

```
public class QuestionAndAnswers
{
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public List<string> Answers { get; set; }
    public int IndexOfCorrectAnswer { get; set; }

    public static QuestionAndAnswers Parse(string qaInput)
    {
        if (qaInput == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(qaInput));

        var result = new QuestionAndAnswers();

        var parts = Regex.Split(qaInput, @"\|?\s+(?=[A-Z]\.)");

        result.Question = parts[0].TrimEnd('.');
        result.Answers = parts.Skip(1).ToList();

        return result;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Question}\n  {string.Join("\n  ", Answers)}";
    }
}
```

Then it can be use something like this:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var input = "What is Facebook?.| A. Website B. Internet C. Social Network D. Game";

    var qa = QuestionAndAnswers.Parse(input);

    Console.WriteLine(qa);

    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Yes I see. Many developers (of course, genius !) here help me so much. But both of you just return one result that output only one string, when I really want the 5 string variable separated! Please help me ~~

Comment: The five strings are separated. One is stored in the `qa.Question` property, and the other 4 are stored in a `List<string>` in the `qa.Answers` property.

Comment: yaya I see ^^ I just try to run again and solved out the expect my output.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Andrey Nasonov's comment said, this is a good application for regular expressions.

The following will get you your split, though I feel like there must be a better way to represent \s(\w.[\w\s]+ repeating four times.

```
Regex splitter = new Regex(@"(.*)\|\s(\w\.[\w\s]+)\s(\w\.[\w\s]+)\s(\w\.[\w\s]+)\s(\w\.[\w\s]+)");
string[] results = splitter.Split(input);

stringA = results[0];
stringB = results[1];
stringC = results[2];
stringD = results[3];
stringE = results[4];
```

Comment: It's return an error "Index was outside the bounds of the array." at line string B = results[1] and corrupt the program without nothing result I expect.

Comment: I just double-checked and it runs as expected for me. Make sure you copied the Regex splitter = new ...... line verbatim. You might also check to see exactly what strings are in results after the split by using a breakpoint and the watch window (I'm assuming you're using Visual Studio).

Comment: Yes do I, but when it running, it make an error at line string B and corrupt everything. I also try to debug and sound like it out of range of array or something that I can't understand!

Comment: If it's giving you an out of range error on line B, that means results.length must equal 1, and it doesn't like you trying to access the second index (because that index doesn't exist). Sounds like it isn't splitting correctly.